# Calculate noise spectral density

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, noise, noise-spectral-density

I want to analytically calculate the power spectral density (PSD) for noise at the input of the given circuit as a function of frequency. Both resistors cause noise, as well as the opamp itself, with *V_n* and *I_n*.

I interpret *V_n* as noise voltage source connected at the positive terminal and *I_n* as current source connected at the negative terminal.

From my current understanding PSD is the total power with reference to a specific frequency *f*.
$$
PSD(f)=\frac{P(f)}{\triangle f}
$$

So what I do is sum all the power values together and divide by the frequency.
$$
PSD(f)=\frac{1}{\triangle f}(\frac{V_n^2}{R_1}+I_n^2(R_2||C)+\frac{4kTR_1 \triangle f}{R_1})=\frac{V_n^2}{R_1\triangle f}+\frac{I_n^2}{\triangle f}\frac{R_2}{2\pi fCR_2+1}+4kT
$$

Is my procedure and the result for calculating the PSD at the input correct?

Note: This is not homework. I am preparing for an exam.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzu53w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: The following picture shall demonstrate what I currently understand under PSD (on the basis of resistor noise):
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you want to calculate PSD rather than output RMS noise (much more useful)?

Comment: It is written in the problem description to calculate PSD. Actually the next thing to do is to calculate the RMS noise (from 100Hz to 100kHz). But I am already stuck with PSD, since I am really unsure if my approach is correct. I cannot really understand it from my course material ..

Comment: Why are you using \$\Delta f\$ as the parameter for your spectral density?  That makes me think you are looking at a specific *bandwidth* rather than a specific frequency, which is incorrect.

Comment: The temperature of the resistors is also going to change with the current going through them, which is impossible to tell... Are you supposed to assume that the noise currents don't heat the resistors?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, yes I did a mistake, changed to PSD(f). Moreover I added a picture showing what I understand under PSD. Concerning the temperature: We are allowed to assume a constant temperature.

Comment: So, your figure is a little confusing.  What is the yellow box?  Are you trying to integrate the psd?  Also, if you add the "@andrew Spott", it will call me and I'll notice this more.

Comment: Ok, good to know, @AndrewSpott ;) Yes, to calculate P_noise for a certain frequency range when knowing the PSD would mean to integrate the PSD in that range (and since the PSD is constant, it simply gets multiplied by Δf)

Comment: So, why do you have a division by \$\Delta f\$ in your PSD function?

Comment: I don't have a division by \$ \Delta f \$ in my PSD function, since it is constant in this example. But if I know \$ P_{noise} \$, I divide it by \$ \Delta f \$ in order to calculate PSD.